# bootstrap 5 navbar collapse is lagging

Tags: css, animation, navigation, bootstrap-5

I need help with bootstrap navbar collapse. When I click the burger menu, there is less than a second lag before it fully expands. Also, if you click very fast, like multiple clicks on the burger icon, the x icon animation gets delayed, and the x becomes the closed icon rather than the burger icons, which is frustrating because I like to have a bit of delay with my nav collapse. please check my link below for a live version :

[My website link](https://wissambaltaci.000webhostapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

So basically I added ul to the `nav-collapse` so now its `.navbar-collapse ul { height: 100vh; }`  so the solution is to set the height of the ul to 100vh, not the height of the whole navbar-collapse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: noted sir i will definitely edit my answer